# Does anyone know this issue with github copilot starting process?

Tags: github, github-copilot

Im trying to install github copilot as extension in my VsCode but it does not start correctly and its not even showing a message for authentication. Im not logged in to github at al on my vscode.

The error i can see in running Extensions is varning sign.
Command 'interactiveEditor.start' appears multiple times in the 'comands' section

Does anyone have this problem or issue? Dont know what to do.

I have tried to reinstall it, reinstall vscode reload, restart an so on. I have checked i have access to github copilot but not in vscode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of error is followed by [community/discussion 51923](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/51923).

Try and downgrade the extension, to check if that would side-step the issue:

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/2232375/231316675-565d32a0-7742-49c5-9aeb-d4e5b46323f3.png]

This maybe related to recent evolution regarding "[Visual Studio Code and GitHub Copilot](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2023/03/30/vscode-copilot)", which will came soon with an in-editor *and Chat view*.
But for that, [joining the waitlist](https://github.com/github-copilot/chat_waitlist_signup/join) for access to the technical preview will be mandatory.